# .NET XML Serialization with a static class in Unity: InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, xml-serialization, unityscript

I'm using Javascript with Unity to save data as XML.
I'm importing parts of the .NET library to give me the XML serialization functionality

I'm trying to take my static `Global` class and turn it into XML.

I get this

```
 InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object 'System.MonoType' is not primitive.
```

When trying to Serialize this

```
static class Global extends System.Object{ 
class buildingData{
    static var posX:int[]=new int[100];
    static var posY:int[]=new int[100];
    static var posZ:int[]=new int[100];
    static var name:String[]=new String[100];
    static var type:int[]=new int[100];
    static var id:int[]=new int[100];
}

class peopleData{
    ///etc.
```

by way of this:

```
var xs : XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Global));
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, Global);
```

Is the problem that my Global class is static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MonoType` is a subclass of `Type` and represents the type-system. If `Global` is a type, I'm surprised that `xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, Global)` even compiles, as `XmlSerializer` expects an *object*, and `Global` there (rather than `typeof(Global)`) shouldn't even resolve AFAIK.

However: indeed, you can't use an object serializer to serialize static state. But as I read it, `Global` doesn't even *have* any state. Basically - give it something that is an actual object instance.